# Possibly eratic documentation? (ABP Tutorial)

Tags: abp

On **ABP.IO Tutorials**, after following the Web Application Tutorial for Blazor & EF.Core, (ABP latest 5.0) on the last part [**10. Book To Author Relation**](https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Tutorials/Part-10?UI=Blazor&DB=EF) the BookAppService implementation kept showing me an errror on every linq query. To be exact, on the overrides for GetAsync and GetListAsync where the linq queries were assembled, the _autorRepository kept showing the following error:
"**CS1503 Cannot convert the Acme.BookStore.Authors.IAuthorsRepostory to System.Collections.IEnumerable**".

The problem dissapeared only when I changed the code **From**:

```
var query = from book in queryable
            join author in _authorRepository on book.AuthorId equals author.Id
            select new { book, author };
```

**To**:

```
  var authors = await _authorRepository.GetQueryableAsync();
  var query = from book in queryable
              join author in authors on book.AuthorId equals author.Id
              select new { book, author };
```

Anybody has experienced the same problem? Is it possibly an error in the documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it was a problem, you can see:　https://github.com/abpframework/abp/pull/11285